# Sequence of integral averages

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, average

Inspired by misreading MEMO 2014 T7.

We call a sequence of $n$ distinct non-negative integers $a_1, a_2, \dots a_n$ meanly if it satisfies the following condition:

For every $k\leq n$, we have:
$$\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k{a_j}\in\mathbb{N}$$
Find the minimum element sum of a meanly sequence of integers of length $n$.

Comments by @Griboullis suggest that the optimal sequence is connected to OEIS [A293688](https://oeis.org/search?q=A293688&sort=&language=&go=Search) for the sum and [A002251](https://oeis.org/A002251) for the $a_j$, which appear linked to upper and lower Wythoff sequences.

Comment: Do you have some answers for small values of $n$? Perhaps inserting that into OEIS might yield a sequence that is the answer. Also, if you could state the original MEMO question it'd be helpful : if only because a solution to that "easier" question might help readers get to the solution of this "harder" question by analogy.

Comment: Sadly, the approaches that yield the original MEMO question are entirely different from those for the above problem...

Comment: The original question had the same constraints as above, but any (!) average of $k$ elements of the sequence had to be integral. This allowed work with lcm s and it was just standard number theory.

Comment: Actually, there is a pattern I see here. The point is that $1+3+5+\ldots + (2n-1) = n^2$, so if I take $a_n = 2n-1$ then $\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i = k^2$ is a multiple of $k$. I wonder if one can do better than this.

Comment: We can do better for at least several odd cases and I that for odd cases, the general answer is $n(n+1)/2$. 
Consider $n=3$ and select the sequence $1,3,2$, for $n=5$ select the sequence $5,3,1,4,2$. I would guess that maybe CRT yields the result but I have no concrete ideas fore evens.

Comment: We can do better for even cases also, consider $n=4$ and $6,2,1,3$.

Comment: the term in the summand should be $a_j$

Comment: @Gribouillis Edited

Comment: My numerical experiments give the sequence OEIS A293688

Comment: Also the $a_j$ sequence appears to be OEIS A002251. I computed up to $n = 16$.

Comment: That's fascinating, thanks a lot